# Simple date histogram?

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch-5

Viewing documents on per weekday classification?
My data is in a format like this:

```
{"text": "hi","created_at": "2016-02-21T18:30:36.000Z"}
```

For this I am using a `dateConversion.groovy` script and kept in the scripts folder in ES 5.1.1.

```
Date date = new Date(doc[date_field].value);
java.text.SimpleDateFormat format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat(format);
format.format(date)
```

When I executed the following code in ES PLUGIN:

```
      "aggs": {
        "byDays": {
            "terms": {
                "script": {
                    "lang": "groovy",
                    "file": "dateConversion",
                    "params": {
                        "date_field": "created_at",
                        "format": "EEEEEE"
                    }
                }
            }
        } ``

I am getting an exception like this:

    {
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Unable to find on disk file script [dateConversion] using lang [groovy]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "testindex-stats",
        "node": "vVhZxH7pQ7CO3qpbYm_uew",
        "reason": {
          "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason": "Unable to find on disk file script [dateConversion] using lang [groovy]"
        }
      }
    ],
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Unable to find on disk file script [dateConversion] using lang [groovy]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Comment: @doelleri i executed your code and getting an error like this??

Comment: Is that script file really in the right directory on every node?

Comment: i kept in the config/scripts/dateConversion.groovy .what is right directory on  every node? can u explain in detail because i am new to this environment

Comment: And i also wanted to know whether groovy scripts work in ES 5.1.1 because when i saw the es_deprecation logs it says that groovy engine is deprecated use painless

Answer (score 0):

To use a script in an aggregation the `script` value is not a string but another object. I think you also need to specify `lang` alongside `file`.

```
"aggs": {
    "byDays": {
        "terms": {
            "script": {
                "lang": "groovy",
                "file": "dateConversion",
                "params": {
                    "date_field": "created_at",
                    "format": "EEEEEE"
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am getting an exception when i used your code..can you help ,in sorting it out?

Comment: @C.Yaswanth if you get errors or exceptions, please have the courtesy of adding them to your question.

Comment: sry .. i am new to this environment .Thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 0):

Some parts of my code need some modifications

```
{
   "aggs": {
    "byDays": {
      "terms": {
        "script":{
          "file":"test",
        "params": {
          "date_field": "created_at",
          "format": "EEEEEE"
        }
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And also my test.groovy code too

```
Date date = new Date(doc[date_field].value);
date.format(format);
```